# What was the nature of Matt's gift to Kelly?

Tags: plot-explanation, girl-next-door

In [The Girl Next Door](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0265208/)'s final scenes, we see Kelly receiving a gift on his newest shoot that is a box of his favourite Cuban Cigars, clearly sent by Matt with a note reading:

> The juice was worth the squeeze.

The question is, is this box meant as a peace offering for their past conflict over Danielle and the numerous deceptions and theft of one another?

Or did Matt want to send him the box as a giant F*** you, essentially saying

> You're a loser, I got the girl AND the money!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow this is one of my favourite films, really not sure how - but I've always read it as a 'clearing the air' gift from an older and wiser Matt.

Answer (score 2):

Well I would say it's a little of both! In the movie, Matt was genuinely a nice guy and even though Kelly beat him up, took his girl, drugged him and what not, there was no grudge on Matt's part as he eventually gets Danielle, goes to Princeton and ends up making a lot of money too.

But that shouldn't stop someone from having the last laugh, right?! And if you remember, Kelly's smirk on reading the note was more of like an involuntary 'tip of the hat'.